# How to stay in dialog triggered by LUIS nodejs

Tags: node.js, dialog, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I'm playing a bit with chatbots using Bot Framework from MS.
I created one supposed to book a flight, and it has LUIS integrated.

My question is: once I'm in the flight booking dialog triggered by LUIS, I want to check if all the informations regarding the flight are given by the user (departure city, arrival city, date, airline...). So if I'm missing an info, for example the city of departure, the bot will ask 'can you give me the departure city?' qnd if I write 'from London', LUIS detects that as a new flight reservation and triggers another dialog. but I want it to stay in the dialog obviously!

Here is the dialog code so far, just in case if departure city is missing:

```
// Main dialog with LUIS
bot.dialog('FlightBookingDialog', [
function (session, args, next) {
    // Resolve and store any entity passed from LUIS.
    var intent = args.intent;

    session.dialogData.airline = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Airline');
    session.dialogData.class = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Class');
    session.dialogData.date_time = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'builtin.datetimeV2');
    session.dialogData.departure = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Departure');
    session.dialogData.destination = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Destination');
    session.dialogData.number_tickets = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'number');

    session.send("I see you want to travel, great !");

    if(!session.dialogData.departure) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Can you specify me a departure city please ?");
    } else {
        next();
    }
},
function (session, args, results, next) {
    if (results.response) {
        builder.LuisRecognizer.recognize(session.message.text, luisModelUrl,
            function(err, intents, entities) {
                if(entities) {
                    var departure = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intents.entities, 'Departure');
                    if (departure) {
                        session.dialogData.departure = departure;
                    }
                }
            }
       );
    };

    session.send("Good !");
},
```

]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'FlightBooking'
});

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you can update the code to have multiple matches. From this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis#handle-the-notecreate-intent) the code may be updated to look like this:

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })
.matches('Greeting', (session) => {
    session.send('You reached Greeting intent, you said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
})
.matches('Note.Create', [(session, args, next) => {
        // Resolve and store any Note.Title entity passed from LUIS.
        var intent = args.intent;
        var title = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Note.Title');

        var note = session.dialogData.note = {
          title: title ? title.entity : null,
        };

        // Prompt for title
        if (!note.title) {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What would you like to call your note?');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    },
    (session, results, next) => {
        var note = session.dialogData.note;
        if (results.response) {
            note.title = results.response;
        }

        // Prompt for the text of the note
        if (!note.text) {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What would you like to say in your note?');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    },
    (session, results) => {
        var note = session.dialogData.note;
        if (results.response) {
            note.text = results.response;
        }

        // If the object for storing notes in session.userData doesn't exist yet, initialize it
        if (!session.userData.notes) {
            session.userData.notes = {};
            console.log("initializing session.userData.notes in CreateNote dialog");
        }
        // Save notes in the notes object
        session.userData.notes[note.title] = note;

        // Send confirmation to user
        session.endDialog('Creating note named "%s" with text "%s"',
            note.title, note.text);
    }])
```

Note that there is no `endDialog` method until the end when the bot has all the information it needs to process the request.

Hope that helps or at least gets you on the right path!

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer.I think I saw that already, the thing is I'm not declaring the intents in mu nodejs code, they are declared directly in my LUIS app on their website, with the web app GUI tool. I don't know if this sample of code can be "combined" with that. But I will try this sample of code to see if I no longer have to trigger problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/docs-samples/Node/basics-naturalLanguage

They are exactly talking about my problem, I post it here so people in the same situation can see it.

You have to go to the `IntentDialog` part, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> it.